# Install error after packaging. ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from invian) (from versions: none)

Tags: python, package, pypi, pyproject.toml

I'm trying to create my first package and upload it to pypi. I've been able to successfully package and upload to testpypi but when I attempted to install it I got this error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas
> (from invian) (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution
> found for pandas

My guess is that there is something wrong with my pyproject.toml file. It currently looks like this:

```
[build-system]
requires      = ["setuptools>=61.0.0", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "invian"
version = "0.0.1"
description="Package to analyze in vivo neural data"
readme = "README.md"
authors = [{ name = "my_name", email = "my_email"}]
license = {file = "LICENSE"}
classifiers = [
    "License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 (GPLv3)",
    'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
    'Intended Audience :: Science/Research',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3'
]
keywords = ["neuroscience", "electrophysiology", "research"]
dependencies = [
    'pandas',
    'numpy',
    'scipy',
    'matplotlib',
    'seaborn'
]
requires-python = ">= 3.6"

[project.urls]
Home = "https://github.com/someuser"
```

Is there something wrong in the way I'm formatting the pyproject.toml file? Also, I'm not using setup.py or setup.cfg.

Thanks!